# Recent iOS deletes local app data

Tags: ios, ipad

I’m having this problem with the most recent iOS versions.  My iBooks, my Notability and my eBreviary apps all routinely loose their data, and have to be reloaded from the cloud/server.  Some process has to be erasing the local copy of the data. Nearly every time i open these apps, my local data has to be retrieved from the cloud somewhere.

This was not occurring with these apps prior to the recent (iOS 11?) release. I’ve looked into the Settings->General->iPad Storage->(App) Offload App possibility, but this is not set for any apps, and I do not have a more general ‘offload’ recommendation/setting to change.

Ideas welcome.

Comment: Have you tried deleting and reinstalling these problem apps (take a backup first, in case it makes things worse though!) This should not be the case, but sometimes local data associated with the App causes problems with the new iOS and reinstalling will erase and recreate this data.

Comment: Yea - but not for all.. The strange part is that the same apps on my iPhone do not exhibit the same behavior. I think it is some setting that I can’t identify. It’s a 16G iPad with 3G free space.